# Is there a way to access env from vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-extensions

I am trying to build a VSCode extension that relies on `process.env` set on runtime from an application like Vue using `process.env.VUE_APP_*` syntax but accessing it on the extension always returns `undefined`.

I'm accessing it on `registerCommand` callback like so:

```js
commands.registerCommand('command', () => console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SOME_NAME));
```

I'm thinking that maybe it has something to do with the way it opened up a new window to run the extension when I'm testing it locally, no?

Comment: what happens when you copy the extension to the extension directory (/home/user/.vscode/extensions) and show an info message

Comment: I tried doing that and it displayed `undefined`

Comment: You want to read the environment of a completely different process (PID)? That will never succeed.

Comment: Seems like it, thank you